# Query Wikidata by GeoNames ID

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I try to query Wikidata for a city by its GeoNames ID.

I can see the id of the property is P1556: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1566

So my query for Berlin (as an example) is:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
   ?id wdt:P1566 wd:2950157
   }
```

But I don't get a match.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple trial and error on Wikidata results in the following: No need for `wd:2950157`, it is a literal, so use only `"2950157"` instead. Use the following (`SERVICE` is used to show the name of the city):

**Edit:** The straightforward method:

```
SELECT ?id ?idLabel WHERE {      
  ?id wdt:P1566 "2950157".      
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
```

**End of EDIT**

**Using BIND or FILTER**

```
SELECT ?id ?idLabel WHERE {
  Bind ("2950157" as ?x)
  ?id wdt:P1566 ?x.      
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
```

Or (a slower option) use `FILTER`

```
 SELECT ?id ?idLabel WHERE {       
    ?id wdt:P1566 ?x.
    filter (?x = "2950157")
    SERVICE wikibase:label {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you use `BIND` and `FILTER` instead of the most obvious usage which is putting the literal in the object position of the triple pattern?

Comment: You are right, I will modify it right away! I am used to work from Jena, I always need plugin points in the query.